# LeakCanary sometimes doesn't report leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'am using **leakcanary-android:1.4-beta** and sometimes does not report leaks. I not understand why, but sometimes I must restart the device or try with another devices but never I found a pattern that I help me to solve this problem.

I seen all issues on the github repository but i have not found anything that help me.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a specific leak pattern you are having problems with? This question is phrased a bit open ended out without a specific problem leak pattern to solve.

Comment: I have no more information , sometimes canary leak reports leaks, but I publish the same project version in other device and does not report leak. This problem was reported in some issues on github or forums. So I have no more data to give. I think that there is any way to check if the lib being logged correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @GastonFlores I work with a lot of devices and yes this does happen sometimes. For my case, this happens mostly on generic and not very popular android phones. All I do is uninstall the application via adb on the terminal  `adb uninstall <package name>` from the device and have android studio reinstall it again. Hope this helps.